# if statement should check part of string exists in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, if-statement

Below code saying substring doesnt exist in current context. Give me someother way to check whether my id contains 'DOM' or 'INT' in my view in mvc.

My table:

[image]

My code:

```
@if( (SUBSTRING(Model.Id,7,9)) !== 'DOM' )
            {
            <tr>
       <td>Amount Approved for Domestic sector : </td>
           <td><input id="Text1" type="text" /></td>

                </tr>
            }
```

Comment: Does it throw any errors, did you search for "C# substring", in other words: what have you tried? Also this model doesn't look optimal. Multiple values in one column usually isn't a good idea. Why not create a "IsDomesticApproved" bit column or whatever the presence of the string "DOM" in the ID field means?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the [`Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa.aspx) method to check if a given string contains a specified substring:

```
@if(Model.Id.Contains("DOM"))
{
    <tr>
        <td>Amount Approved for Domestic sector : </td>
        <td><input id="Text1" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
}
```

or:

```
@if(Model.Id.Split('/')[1].Trim() == "DOM")
{
    <tr>
        <td>Amount Approved for Domestic sector : </td>
        <td><input id="Text1" type="text" /></td>
    </tr>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
@if((Model.Id.Substring(7,9)) !== 'DOM')
```

Since `Substring` is a method of `String`